# Checking a value in python

Tags: python

I have to enter a number into a list on a user given position.

How can I check if the value of the position is not a string or a value lower than 0?

This is what I've tried:

```
while True:
    poz=input("Give the position:")
    try:
        val=int(poz)
        if poz>=0:
            break
        else:
            print ("The position has to be bigger then 0")
    except ValueError:
        print ("invalid number")
```

Comment: So what's the *problem* with what you have?

Comment: it doesn't work and i don't know why

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"doesn't work"*? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: @MarcMoldovan You have to be more detailed than that. Did you get exceptions? Bad results? Explosions?

Comment: When i enter string instead of int it works, but if i enter a int it goes to an infinite cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking against `pos` instead of `val`

```
while True:
    poz=input("Give the position:")
    try:
        val=int(poz)
        if val>=0:
            break
        else:
            print ("The position has to be bigger then 0")
    except ValueError:
        print ("invalid number")
```

Comment: Play FGITW, expect to get shot on occasion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've learnt a new acronym at least. Thank you. :D